# Can I overcome the inbuilt JSON length limit during serialisation of a GridView?

Tags: json, gridview, serialization

This is a very similar question to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) but since that is now four years old I thought I wouldn't keep adding to it.  I am also getting the error

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
```

but this happens in a standard ASP.NET application rather than MVC.  My application creates a single data-table with an enormous number of *columns* (and a handful of rows) and binds it to a GridView (in fact a Telerik RadGrid -- I am assuming the difference is not significant).  The error then occurs during the Render event of the grid:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DescribeProperties(IScriptDescriptor descriptor)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrar.GetScriptDescriptors(Control control)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompositeDataBoundControl.GetScriptDescriptors()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.RegisterScriptDescriptors(IScriptControl scriptControl)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompositeDataBoundControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
...
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at ASP.commoncontrols_ccesdmarginals_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\Websites\CCESD\CommonControls\CCESDMarginals.ascx:line 12
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at CCESD.Web.Controls.CCESDMarginals.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) in d:\Websites\CCESD\CommonControls\CCESDMarginals.ascx.cs:line 121
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.RenderPageInAjaxMode(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control page)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I have tried setting `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>` in the web.config file but this hasn't made a difference, which isn't altogether surprising given that I'm not using a web service.  I've also tried the following web.config settings, all to no effect:

```
  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2147483647"/>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647"/>
  <add key="aspnet:UpdatePanelMaxScriptLength" value="2147483647" />
```

The second answer down in the other link ([Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)) seems to sum up my situation but since I'm not using MVC I'm not sure how to make use of their answer.  Is there a way to somehow override the internal serialisation process of a GridView (or equivalent) in order for it to work with arbitrarily large tables?